# How to save the chat log locally and access in Bot framework NodeJS v4?

Tags: node.js, botframework

A logger is implemented as a  middle-ware. Need to access the output of the logger through another dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Botbuilder-Samples repo, the 17.multilingual-conversations [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/17.multilingual-conversations). It demonstrates how you can interact with the dialog by receiving and sending activities based around the current context and inputs.

First, assign your middleware to the adapter in the index.js file:

```js
const { LoggerMiddleware } = require('./logger-middleware');

adapter.use(new LoggerMiddleware (parameter_1, parameter_2));
```

Like the translator-middleware.js file, you will want to pass any necessary parameters thru the constructor of your middleware file:

```js
constructor(parameter_1, parameter_2) {
        this.parameter_1 = parameter_1;
        this.parameter_2 = parameter_2;
    }
```

After which, you create the onTurn method (and any associated methods), passing in the context and utilizing the class constructor parameters you need. Here you can create new dialogs that make use of the passed in logged data.

```js
async onTurn(turnContext, next) {
    let loggerText = this.parameter_1;
    [...do stuff with <loggerText> data...]

    await next();
}
```

In many respects, the middleware looks and functions like your main bot.js file. It is simply called at a different point in the process.

Hope of help.